# How do I expose a USB device to the Java API through HAL?

Tags: android, usb, drivers, hal, sparkcore

> Background:

I'm trying to integrate a new sensor into an Android platform.  For development purposes, I am using a Nvidia Jetson-TK1 dev board and a Spark Core.  The Spark Core communicates with the sensor and outputs the data serially through USB.

At a high level, my needs are:

- To be able to read/write serial data to the Spark Core over USB
- To handle the data with Android Service written with the API
- Accomplish all this at high speeds

In the future when I become more experienced at working with the HAL, I may eliminate the Spark Core completely and use the GPIO pins on the Jetson to control the sensor IC.

> Onto the Details:

I can read the data through the command `cat /dev/ttyACM0`, but I'm looking for a more low-level approach.  I want to use the HAL to communicate with the device.  Specifically, I want the Spark Core to show up when I `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`.
Then I want to be able to read the data using `getevent /dev/input/eventXX`.

> The Main Question:

Here is my approach:

1. Find or develop a USB device driver in native C code
2. Use JNI to compile the driver within Android source code
3. Create a HAL module (.so binary) with a HAL definition
4. Compile Android source code into the kernel
5. Flash onto the Jetson
6. Profit

Is this correct? Can someone point me in the direction of what I would take as a first step? I'm mostly confused because I know Android is built on the Linux kernel and the Linux kernel should have USB device drivers built into it (right?)